# use a multi-line variable array in a SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a large data set that holds the names and addresses of our customers.  I need to allow the user to search this data set, however the user rarely has the key field necessary to make the search easy.  They do however have three key values that will get them a reasonable subset to work with.  They have the customer's last name, street and zip code.  While this does not assure a single match, for the most part I should be in the less than 10 returns range.  I am guessing most will only return 1 value.
I would like to have the user submit multiple lines of the three values and then return the appropriate values to user.  I am looking at putting a new value in my table that has the three values concatenated, but I would have approximately 19 MM rows of data affected.  I was wondering if there was some way with SSRS to submit an array variable with the three fields and then return multiple lines based on the values?
I am using SQL Server 2012 as the database.

Comment: Could you not use a series of OR statements in your SQL? Something like  `where Surname like '%' + (@var) + '%' or zipcode like '%' + (@var) + '%' or street like '%' + (@var) + '%'`

Comment: You would need to split the variable and then use the `OR` operator in your select statement to return the data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes like BishNabo wrote, In your SQL just add the below structure with your field and table names. I've wrapped @var in wildcards to allow for partial values. This format requires all three to be submitted by the user.

```
Where tbl.fld_LName LIKE '%@LastName%' and tbl.fld_StreetName LIKE '%@Street%' and tbl.fld_ZipCode LIKE '%@Zip%'
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d6952bd0-af17-403f-8402-02759a9517fb/execute-tsql-on-ssrs-2012-with-3-parameters?forum=transactsql